# Optimizing a Time Range Function

Tags: python, performance, datetime, optimization

I would like to optimize the execution time of a Python function which makes heavy usage of the builtin `datetime` utilities. My function is working as-is, but it's slow.

```
# Check if an ending date (stored in a YYYY-MM-DD string) is
# within range of a beginning date (in the same format). Two
# numbers, the min/max length, define how soon/distant the 2nd
# date can be from the 1st.

minDelayLength = 1
maxDelayLength = 999

def checkDateRange(dateStr1, dateStr2):
    date1 = datetime.strptime(dateStr1, '%Y-%m-%d')
    date2 = datetime.strptime(dateStr2, '%Y-%m-%d')

    minLimit = date1 + timedelta(days=minDelayLength)
    maxLimit = date1 + timedelta(days=maxDelayLength)

    return minLimit <= date2 <= maxLimit
```

Running 1,000,000 calls of this function takes about 40 seconds on my computer, so I profiled one run of the function using `cProfile` to look for performance issues. I found that it makes a large amount of function calls:

```
2634 function calls (2548 primitive calls) in 0.050 seconds
```

Does anyone have suggestions for how to improve the performance of my function? I can assume that the function's input will always be valid (properly formatted), and I can assume that the min/max lengths won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowest part of your code is `strptime`. If you are sure that the date string is always formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` you can use the method below, which made it 11 times faster (tested on 500000 calls).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

minDelayLength = timedelta(days=1)
maxDelayLength = timedelta(days=999)

def checkDateRange(dateStr1, dateStr2):
    date1 = date(int(dateStr1[:4]), int(dateStr1[5:7]), int(dateStr1[8:10]))  
    date2 = date(int(dateStr2[:4]), int(dateStr2[5:7]), int(dateStr2[8:10]))  

    return date1 + minDelayLength <= date2 <= date1 + maxDelayLength
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a superb answer. And you didn't discuss it, but the way you initialized the lengths as timedeltas is another good improvement. I benchmarked this new code on the same 1,000,000 calls as before, and it runs in 3.5 seconds now, compared to 40.0 before.